# How to prove this cauchy problem has a unique solution on entire $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

On an old exam, I found the following problem. Given a cauchy problem $y' = e^{-y^2} (y^{2014} - y^{2013})$ and $y(x_0) = y_0$, do the following:

i) prove that there is exactly $C^1$ function on $\mathbb{R}$, which solves this cauchy problem

ii) determine if there exist such $x_0, y_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, such that the graph of solution of this cauchy's problem goes through $(a, \frac{1}{2}), (b, \frac{3}{2})$.

I guess I should first of all choose a rectangle around point $(x_0, y_0)$, let's say $[x_0 - a, x_0 + a] \times [y_0 - b, y_0 + b]$ and somehow bound the functions $f(x,y) = e^{-y^2} (y^{2014} - y^{2013})$ and $f_y (x,y) = e^{-y^2} (-2y^{2015} - 2 y^{2014} + 2014 y^{2013} - 2013 y^{2012})$ on this rectangle. The problem is, I can't do it at all; I have no idea how to bound this function. If I could do that, I suppose, I would be able to find out the maximal interval where the solution is well defined, by $(x_0 - \alpha, x_0 + \alpha)$, where $\alpha = \min \{ a, \frac{b}{M}, \frac{1}{L} \}$, where $M$ is the upper bound of this function and $L$ is the upper bound of derivative. After that, my plan would be to try to extend the interval by choosing points moving towards the border of the interval. However, I'm already stuck at trying to bound $f$ and $f_y$, so I would be very happy if anyone can help.

As for the second part, I would also appreciate any hint that could help me approach it (but please don't tell me the solution).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Question 1

Let $f(y) = e^{-y^2} (y^{2014} - y^{2013})$. As $f$ is locally Lipschitz, the [Initial Value Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_value_problem) $y^\prime(t) = f(y(t))$ and $y(x_0)=y_0$ has a unique maximal solution according to Picard-Lindelöf theorem.
If $y_0 \in \{0,1\}$, then the constant map $y(t)=y_0$ is the unique solution defined on $\mathbb R$.

Otherwise, we can rewrite the equation as
$$\int_{y_0}^{y(x)} \frac{e^{u^2}}{u^{2013}(u-1)} du = x-x_0$$

Now, you can notice that:

- If $y_0 \lt 0$ the solution is increasing to $0$ but can't reach $0$ as otherwise we would get two solutions.
- If $0 \lt y_0 \lt 1$ the solution is decreasing to $0$ but can't reach $0$.
- If $y_0 \gt 1$ the solution is increasing.

Finally, use the fact that $\int_{-1}^0 \frac{du}{f(u)}$, $\int_{0}^{1/2} \frac{du}{f(u)}$ and $\int_{2}^\infty \frac{du}{f(u)}$ are all diverging integral to prove that in each of the three cases above, the IVP is defined on $\mathbb R$.

Question 2

If a solution would pass through the two given points, if would exist $c \in \mathbb R$ such that $y(c) = 1$. This would contradict the uniqueness of the IVP.

Comment: I don't understand a few steps here.
(1) If $y_0 \in \{0, 1\}$, how do we know this solution is unique on all $\mathbb{R}$?
(2) When you split the solution in three possibilities, what do you mean by "solution is increasing / decreasing"? How do we see that? I'm not sure, as our formula only describes $x$, not $y$, which is the solution?
(3) How does that fact that these three integrals diverge show that the IVP is defined and unique on $\mathbb{R}?

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: (1) Because in that case, the constant map defined on $\mathbb R$ and equal to $y_0$ is an evident solution. (2) That the solution is an increasing/decreasing map. (3) because the integral equation implies that if the integrals diverge, $x - x_0 \to \infty$.